# How to convert XSD Simple Type to rdfs:Datatype using Jena

Tags: xsd, jena, owl, rdfs

Suppose I have an XSD file having below lines of code;

```
<xsd:simpleType name="test">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

What I am trying to do is to convert this xsd simple type into an instance of rdfs:Datatype in an ontology. Below is what I want.

```
<rdfs:Datatype rdf:about="http://www.example.org/example1/#testDatatype">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
  <owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:Datatype>
      <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
      <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description>
          <xsd:maxLength rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          >50</xsd:maxLength>
        </rdf:Description>
      </owl:withRestrictions>
    </rdfs:Datatype>
  </owl:equivalentClass>
</rdfs:Datatype>
```

How do I do this using Jena?

Comment: Let me see if I understand it correctly: you would like a piece of code that parses an XSD type definition and automatically create the corresponding `rdfs:Datatype`, right? I am not sure Jena can do this on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can do this with the below code. I parse XSD with XSOM. Assume that I stored "test" simpletype in a variable called "simple" (XSSimpleType).

```
String URI = simple.getTargetNamespace() + "#" + simple.getName() + "Datatype";
OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
OntClass datatype = ontology.createOntResource(OntClass.class, RDFS.Datatype, URI);                 

Resource onDatatype = XSD.xstring;

OntClass equivClass = ontology.createOntResource(OntClass.class, RDFS.Datatype, null);
equivClass.addProperty(OWL2.onDatatype, onDatatype);
datatype.addEquivalentClass(equivClass);
```

It is not a complete code and it does not include the code segment related with parsing XSD but I hope it will give the idea.

Comment: If this worked for you, be sure to accept your answer!